# How hammering my TV remote make it working?

Tags: everyday-life, electronics

I often do this while my remote battery gets low, I just hammer my TV remote two of three times. I have seen this to be work with other devices. But I never bother thinking about how this makes things working. So My question why this works? Is there any physics or it just happens because the part gets loose or something?

Comment: +1 for the presence of science in mind

Answer (score 2):

The connections between ends of battery and device get degraded over time owing to chemical reactions such as oxidation. Also the springiness of the contacts goes down owing to metal fatigue. By moving the battery you slide it a little across the connection. This can either result in it finding a place on the contact with less oxidation, or it can scrape an oxide layer away and increase the connection that way. I think this is the main contributing factor here, but there might be some similar effect inside the battery, depending on its design.

Comment: That's make a little sense. but note this happen only with old batteries. But metal fatigue already there when I put a new battery but that doesn't affect the  working very much.

Answer (score 0):

My guess: The connection between battery and remote increases a bit, because you move the battery around by shaking it (quite a loose part compared to the rest). Suddenly, there is enough energy again for it to work, since before it fell just under the minimum power level.

The conductance can increase because there is either just more surface connecting the two or the shaking scraped away some corroded material.

Comment: Looseness can happen with new cells too but why this happens to old cells?

Comment: With new cells, a slight difference in conductance will not make a difference, there is enough power in any case. But when the batteries are low (just below the minimum power requirement), it can make the difference between working and not working.

Answer (score 0):

It was suggested in an answer to a similar question (which I cannot track down, sorry), that jostling the batteries may also redistribute the dielectric gel, in such batteries as have a soft dielectric.  This would lead to improved power delivery rate, at least temporarily.